# How to use base64 string instead of URL in Leaflet ImageOverlay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I am using ImageOverlay layer to print an overlay image over a map using Leaflet. If I use an image that is accessible online, i.e. using Leaflet [example](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#imageoverlay):

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

everything works fine. **I would however like to use an base64 encoded string as the image.** This string is precomputed somewhere else in my script.

How should I insert such string in instead of a URL path?

PS: I am using **angularjs**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass your base64-encoded image string as `L.imageOverlay`'s 1st parameter, i.e. instead of your `imageUrl`:

```js
var map = L.map('map');

var imageUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
var imageBounds = [
  [40.712216, -74.22655],
  [40.773941, -74.12544]
];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(imageBounds);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: This is actually what I have tried, but the mistake I made was I sent a wrong string! Thank you, now I realised! Thanks again, works like a charm.

Comment: For anyone interested, if you are sending the base64 string from Zeppelin python as I did, use this:
`z.angularBind('image', {"img":base64encoded_string.decode('ascii')})`
Especially this **base64encoded_string.decode** is important! Otherwise it will be a binary string (with 3 more characters).